# Can a good cleric prepare Inflict Light Wounds?

Tags: dnd-3.5e, spells, cleric

Inflict Light Wounds is listed in the 3.5e PHB as a Necromancy spell but with *no* alignment descriptor at all.  I cannot find anything in the PHB that prevents a Good-aligned Cleric from *preparing* that spell, even if they cannot cast it spontaneously.  Is there some RAW somewhere else that prevents Good clerics from using unaligned Cleric spells from the Necromancy school?

Answer (score 22):

You can prepare any of the *inflict wounds* spells as a Good Aligned Cleric, because they do not have the *Evil* descriptor. What you **can't** do is spontaneously cast your prepared spells as *inflict wounds* spells in the same way that you can do that for *cure wounds* spells. It doesn't have anything to do with the Necromancy school of magic. The Necromancy school is not necessarily *Evil*, so there is no alignment restriction for casting Necromancy Spells.

Comment: I feel like the line about the Cure spells not being necromancy could be made a little clearer.

Answer (score 2):

There is no prohibition to my knowledge.

I believe the citation you're thinking of is:

> **Chaotic, Evil, Good, and Lawful Spells**
>   A cleric can’t cast spells of an alignment opposed to his own or his deity’s (if he has one). Spells associated with particular alignments are indicated by the chaos, evil, good, and law descriptors in their spell descriptions.

REF: http://www.d20srd.org/srd/classes/cleric.htm#chaoticEvilGoodandLawfulSpells

Interestingly, per letter of the rules I read, a good cleric could even prepare evil spells, though couldn't cast them.

Comment: So just to be sure: that means that a Neutral Good cleric of a Lawful Good god cannot cast spells with either the Evil or the Chaotic descriptor, right?

Comment: @ThomasJacobs That is my understanding of/per that quote.  If there are other passages that trump it, they'd likely be helpful to the Q.